# Синтаксис типа ...$guards

Tags: php

Что значит синтаксис типа `public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)` ? Что за три точки?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В версиях PHP 5.6 и выше список аргументов может содержать многоточие ..., чтобы показать, что функция принимает переменное количество аргументов. Аргументы в этом случае будут переданы в виде массива. Например:

```
<?php
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $acc = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
?>
```

Результат выполнения данного примера:

```
10
```

Многоточие (...) можно использовать при вызове функции, чтобы распаковать массив (array) или Traversable переменную в список аргументов:

```
<?php
function add($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

echo add(...[1, 2])."\n";

$a = [1, 2];
echo add(...$a);
?>
```

Результат выполнения данного примера:

```
3
3
```

[Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php)